# SWTOR security key and app

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I'm curious if you can set up the mobile key on a android and then order the physical key later and then use it too? I am always misplacing either my phone or keys and would like to have the ability to use either to login with.

Answer (score 10):

No. The two are not * interchangeable*, and you can only associate one or the other with your account at a given time.

You *can* however freely switch between the two at the SWTOR website, but you'll need to have both devices (your smartphone, and the key fob) on hand to switch between them. (i.e., if you wanted to use an Android device *for now* while you wait for a physical key to be shipped.)

Comment: @NicShaydes If this answers your question, please click on the **Check Mark** icon next to it, to *accept* the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Possibly a related question, what happens if you use the app and upgrade/replace your smartphone with a new model?

Comment: @Shadur That could be a problem. Right now there's a known issue where if you remove a mobile security key from your account you can't add another one. You can add and remove physical keys all day long, but it will not let you add and remove the app normally. It's possible they've fixed this though.

Comment: @Shadur Speaking from experience with WoW's app, rather than SWTOR's in this case: you'll need to remove and re-add it for it to continue working. The app seeds it's RNG based on some specific identifying info from a given phone. Software updates and hardware changes can change this seed. Since you need the key to remove the key, **always remove your security key before making changes to your phone.** (I have a physical key for SWTOR, so I can't speak to the issues Atreusmonk refers to, which would exacerbate this problem of course.)

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz unfortunately the statement of atreusmonk is correct. The more enervating problem is that there is only one way of removing the mobile security: call customer support. This is free for US, UK, Germany, France.